# Latest Ubuntu and Secure Boot

Tags: ubuntu, secure-boot

Can anyone tell me whether it is necessary, or even recommended to disable Secure Boot in UEFI before doing a fresh Ubuntu installation?

Ditto for CSM or Legacy Boot(BIOS) mode.

I leave both untouched from their defaults(enabled) and only disabled Fast Boot in UEFI before my most recent install (Ubuntu-mate 16.04).

CSM enabled in my ASUS UEFI-BIOS means UEFI+Legacy Oprom are supported, which I assume means attempt UEFI first and fall back to BIOS Legacy if UEFI isn't supported.

Although I had to boot a couple times before my new Linux install was recognized by UEFI, didn't seem to have any other issues.
Just wondering is the 'disable Secure Boot' only applies to older versions of Ubuntu, or if there is some other advantage to doing so?

Comment: Secure boot is useless to anyone not using a computer for "sensitive" work. Its actual main use is to prevent people from easily installing another OS than greedy spying Windows. So you can safely disable it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it only applies to older versions of Ubuntu. The current release supports secure boot and there's no reason to disable it.

Comment: There's a reason to disable it: it is absolutely useless.

Comment: @cylgalad are you referring to [attacks like this](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/44223.html)? I'd say it's still useful to know your boot hasn't been tampered with...

Comment: It's useless to 99% of people because nobody will bother to "attack" your boot and if you don't use full disk encryption, there's absolutely no need of this "secure" boot since anyone can read your files anyway. Only work computers for such nazis as the NSA, CIA, FBI, etc actually need such crap. Your home computer doesn't need it at all, and we didn't need it in the past despite the few old boot viruses of DOS era.